# IPA: Question Marks

Tags: ipa

Came across this while looking up some information for Chinese dialects.

[image: examples]

What do the question marks mean as an IPA symbol?

Comment: They're not question marks but [glottal stops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glottal_stop).

Comment: Out of curiosity, what topolect is this? I speak standard Cantonese, and our plosive codas all have no audible release, a phenomenon that is said to be due to an overlapping glottal stop (in fact, I've seen our phonotactic constraints characterised as 'a syllable may only end in a nasal sound or the glottal stop...), although I'm not sure if the analysis is accurate (since I don't feel any glottal stop when I articulate those sounds, haha).

Comment: It does look pretty weird, though! This question has some information about why this symbol was chosen: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/213/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-the-selection-of-the-ipa-symbols

Comment: @WavesWashSands It's supposed to be 苏州 topolect/dialect (whichever you prefer).

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut you should write up you comment in to an answer.

Comment: @DangerFourpence I fell a bit mercenary doing it, but I have written it up as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The IPA symbol that is similar to a question mark is the [glottal stop symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glottal_stop_(letter)), which indicates the [glottal stop phone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glottal_stop), a sound made by completely obstructing and then releasing airflow at the glottis. This sound occurs as a phoneme in many languages and is very common as an allophone and/or articulatory artefact in most. In san serif fonts the glottal stop symbol may appear identical to a question mark but without the dot below [ʔ], or have a horizontal serif at the base as in the following:

[image: []]

According to [Pullum and Ladusaw (1986, p185)](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=b7ml0qh2HMcC&pg=PR32&lpg=PR32&dq=pullum+and+ladusaw+1986+phonetic+symbol+guide&source=bl&ots=iCvkwo9MM5&sig=XUOIi0Wa9oJOKw-aLNDxuMBQvq4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Hy2jVZfCFafHmwXYlIKABQ&ved=0CEAQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=pullum%20and%20ladusaw%201986%20phonetic%20symbol%20guide&f=false) the glottal stop symbol does originally derive from the use of the actual question mark symbol to indicate a glottal stop.